# Leadership: who builds the cohort?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

Is there specific text that specifies who (GM or player) actually builds the cohort?

... being an NPC implies that the GM does, but is that explicitly spelled out anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Ultimate Campaign has your answer:

From the [archives of Nethys](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Advancing%20Companions&Category=Companions)

> When you select the Leadership feat, you and the GM should discuss the cohort’s background, personality, interests, and role in the campaign and party. Not only does this give the GM the opportunity to reject a cohort concept that goes against the theme of the campaign, but the GM can plan adventure hooks involving the cohort for future quests. The random background generator in Chapter 1 can help greatly when filling in details about the cohort. Once the discussion is done, writing down a biography and personality profile of the cohort helps cement his role in the campaign and provides a strong reference point for later talks about what is or is not appropriate advancement for the cohort.

It seems pretty clear here that this is a "player writes it, GM approves it" situation, with the GM oversight being in order to support having the cohort properly integrated into the campaign.  Similarly, the character build (largely controlled by the PC) is expected to grow directly from that background, or at least not conflict with it.

#### However...

The fact is that Leadership with full build control is a *very* powerful feat in the hands of anyone who has a reasonable degree of skill at character optimization (and fairly powerful even without).  Leadership and associated feats are often banned by houserule as a result, and the 2nd edition equivalents have been nerfed *heavily* (and are solid options even so).  If you're playing a game with people who optimize heavily, and you allow leadership, then it is reasonably likely that they will all take it, and that your party will suddenly become *significantly* more powerful (and also unwieldy) as a result.  If you have only two or three players, that might actually be good.  If you have six or seven already, it is likely to be problematic.

In general, as a DM, you might want to seriously consider not allowing this feat.  If you do allow it, and you have high-optimization players, you might want to seriously consider houseruling limitations on the degree to which they get to optimize their cohorts.

Comment: [Ultimate Campaign](https://www.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Advancing%20Companions&Category=Companions) gives guidance specifically about advancing Cohorts

Comment: @Ifusaso fair.  I'll take a look at that and see if there's anythign there that I can use to enhance the answer.

Comment: @Ifusaso Well.  That jsut changed my *entire answer*.

Comment: @BenBarden updoot, but I liked your original answer better.

Answer (score 3):

#### Generally speaking, the player should be building the Cohort.

While you are correct that it being an NPC implies that a DM should build it, Ultimate Combat specifically states that it should be the player who makes any choices about the class, feats, and other such attributes of advancement.

**Ultimate Campaign** <sub>pg. 142</sub>

> **Cohort:** Advancement choices for a cohort include feats, skills, ability score increases, and class levels.
>
> **A cohort is generally considered a player-controlled companion, and therefore you get to decide how the cohort advances.** The GM might step in if you make choices that are inappropriate for the cohort, use the cohort as a mechanism for pushing the boundaries of the game rules, or treat the cohort unfairly. A cohort is a loyal companion and ally to you, and expects you to treat him fairly, generously, without aloofness or cruelty, and without devoting too much attention to other minions such as familiars or animal companions. The cohort’s attitude toward you is generally helpful (as if using the Diplomacy skill); he complies with most of your requests without any sort of skill check, except for requests that are against his nature or put him in serious peril.
>
> If you exploit your cohort, you’ll quickly find your Leadership score shrinking away. Although this doesn’t change the cohort’s level, the cohort can’t gain levels until your Leadership score allows for a level increase, so if you’re a poor leader, you must wait longer for your cohort to level up. In extreme cases, the cohort might abandon you, and you’ll have to recruit a new cohort.

The only time a DM should step in on the process is if one of the following issues (or something similar but not listed) comes up.

> Examples of inappropriate advancement choices are a good-aligned companion selecting morally questionable feats, a clumsy cohort suddenly putting many ranks in Disable Device (so he can take all the risks in searching for traps instead of you), a spellcaster cohort taking nothing but item creation feats (so you get access to plenty of cheap magic items at the cost of just one feat, Leadership), a fighter cohort taking a level in wizard when he had no previous interest in magic, or you not interacting with your cleric cohort other than to gain defensive spells from a different class or a flanking bonus.
>
> When you select the Leadership feat, you and the GM should discuss the cohort’s background, personality, interests, and role in the campaign and party. Not only does this give the GM the opportunity to reject a cohort concept that goes against the theme of the campaign, but the GM can plan adventure hooks involving the cohort for future quests. The random background generator in Chapter 1 can help greatly when filling in details about the cohort. Once the discussion is done, writing down a biography and personality profile of the cohort helps cement his role in the campaign and provides a strong reference point for later talks about what is or is not appropriate advancement for the cohort.

A good example is having a cleric companion who worships a good aligned god(dess) take a Damnation feat at level up, which would be diametrically opposed to their character and outside the bounds of good role-play. Another example is having a wizard companion only have Craft [X] feats and forcing them to stay at home crafting you magical trinkets, in which case, you've essentially given yourself multiple crafting feats for the cost of a single feat slot, which would *definitely* cause issues with game balance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120674/discussion-on-answer-by-revenantbacon-leadership-who-builds-the-cohort).

Comment: Just to be clear: The GM builds the initial cohort, but when the cohort gains a level the player decides how the cohort advances. Is that accurate?

Comment: @HeyICanChan No, the player has complete control over the cohort from the beginning.

Comment: These quotations, though, seem to address only advancement (cf. [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/character-advancement/)) rather than initial creation (e.g. [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/character-creation/)). Am I missing something?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Is there enough difference between character creation and character advancement that they shouldn't be considered part of the same process? Where does character creation end and advancement begin when you're putting together a new level 3 character? After assigning stats and race? After picking the first class level? The second? The third? I think you're starting to really split hairs here and it doesn't seem to be particularly helpful argument to make. *The player has complete control, **period.***

Comment: First, I think this is from *Ultimate Campaign* not *Combat.* Second, to confirm, you *don't* see a difference between a new third level character entering play and an existing character advancing during play from level 3 to level 4? If you do see a difference, then it sounds like the GM does the former and the player manages the latter. If you don't see the difference, then you're right that we're done here. (And that's totally okay, by the way. `:-)`)

Comment: @HeyICanChan No, I see character creation and character advancement as a single process, with character creation just being the *beginning* of that same process. Also, thanks for noting my typo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120730/discussion-between-hey-i-can-chan-and-revenantbacon).